# Is there a way to make a conditional validation annotation and bind it in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, caliburn.micro

I have a few fields, one being year and another being state.  The year should only be required if the state is not the home state.  I don't want to have to wait until the user clicks submit and then notify them at that point, that the year is now required.  I'm using other custom AnnotationValidator's but none that are conditional like this one needs to be.

I ran across this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx which does exactly what I'm wanting.  The only problem is that it's not using Caliburn and I can't figure out how to register the validator and the attribute like it's doing here in Global.asax.

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(RequiredIfAttribute), 
    typeof(RequiredIfValidator));
```

I tried doing some research on ConventionManager.ApplyValidation because it looked promising, but couldn't find anything close to what I need it to do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not create a custom validation and put it in your property and enable the ValidatesOnError (xaml) to true?

Comment: Can you please show the code snippet where the author registers in Global.asax.